# Issue regarding responsive datatable on heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku, datatables, responsive

I have a ruby on rails app hosted on heroku. I have used datatable in one of my page. And I have made it responsive so that in smaller width mobile devices some of the columns will be visible with a green circular plus button on the left side of each row. And clicking on that button all the other columns for the row will be visible. And it is working fine in my localhost. But when I am going to deploy it on heroku, all those features are working fine except the green circular plus button is not visible. But clicking on the space where the green circular plus button should have appeared ,other columns become visible. So on heroku it working well except the green plus button is not visible.

I have executed the command:

```
bundle exec assets:precomplile
```

But still is not working.

My code for that particular page is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tables - PixelAdmin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.2/css/dataTables.responsive.css"/>
<style>
    body {
        font-size: 140%;
    }

    table.dataTable th,
    table.dataTable td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body class="theme-default main-menu-animated" style="padding-top: 40px;">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0"
               width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Serial No.</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Creation Time</th>
        <th>Updation Time</th>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= article.id %></td>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= article.title %></td>
  <td><%= article.text %></td>
  <td><%= article.created_at %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td><%= article.updated_at %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>




<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.2/js/dataTables.responsive.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example')
            .dataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "dom": '<"top"lf>t<"bottom"pi><"clear">'
            });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!!

The link of that page on my heroku app is:

https://workerq.herokuapp.com/articles

And my localhost screenshot is:

[image]

Comment: Your default.js and default.css not loaded into the web page. Please do the testing properly by opening the web console. And if still not solved then you can run the localhost application in production mode. That will help you to figure out the actual problem.

Comment: how to add default.js and default.css on herokuapp? Because both of these two files are already in my local directory. So when I am pushing it to heroku, why it is not being uploaded on heroku? @Bharatsoni

Comment: That you have to check.

Comment: I have changed the javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag from 'default' to 'application' respectively. And it solved my problem. Thanks for giving the hint to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the errors in your page, I found something interesting:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://workerq.herokuapp.com/articles' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

every load from cdn gave an error like this one above, my sugestion is for you to use the gems bootstrap-sass and jquery-datatables-rails instead of the cdn.